# Calculate the sum depending on column php

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have the following array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [year_col] => 2016
        [week_col] => 21
        [total] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [year_col] => 2016
        [week_col] => 22
        [total] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [year_col] => 2016
        [week_col] => 22
        [total] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [year_col] => 2016
        [week_col] => 22
        [total] => 3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [year_col] => 2016
        [week_col] => 23
        [total] => 2
    )
)
```

I neet to get the sum of `total` for each `week_col`. In this case I want to get : 
`21 => 1, 22 => 7, 23 => 2`
I try :

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $draw){  
    $a_filter_draws[$draw['week_col']] = array(
       'total_a' => $sum+=$draw['total']
    );
}
```

Can you help me please ? It don't return the good sum. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $arrSum = array();
    foreach($array as $draw){  
        if(isset($arrSum[$draw['week_col']])) {
           $arrSum[$draw['week_col']] += $draw['total'];
        } else {
           $arrSum[$draw['week_col']] = $draw['total'];
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Cool, now looks definitely better :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a_filter_draws = array();
foreach($array as $draw){  
  if (!isset($a_filter_draws[$draw['week_col']])) {
    $a_filter_draws[$draw['week_col']] = 0;
  }

  $a_filter_draws[$draw['week_col']] += $draw['total'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr=Array
(Array
    (
        "year_col" => 2016,
        "week_col" => 21,
        "total" => 1
    )
,Array
    (
        "year_col" => 2016,
        "week_col" => 22,
        "total" => 2
    )
, Array
    (
        "year_col" => 2016,
        "week_col" => 22,
        "total" => 2
    )
, Array
    (
        "year_col" => 2016,
        "week_col" => 22,
        "total" => 3
    )
,Array
    (
        "year_col" => 2016,
        "week_col" => 23,
        "total" => 2
    )
);

$sum = 0;
$total=0;
    foreach($arr as $draw){  

      $sum+=$draw["week_col"];
      $total+=$draw["total"];
    }
    echo $sum;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $total;
?>
```